# wpml languages redirecting to default

Tags: wordpress, redirect, wpml

I'm not too familiar with WPML and I site I am working on is using it. Everything was working fine, but now it has been noticed that when you go to a different language domain (e.g. www.domain.com/es/pagename) the site seems to rewrite the address to (www.domain.com/pagename) removing the language directory from the web address making some language pages unaccessable.
This is not occurring on all pages though.

I checked the htaccess file and the rewrite are their.

Any help or information on this would be great.

Answer (score 0):

Try check settings of WPML plugin http://take.ms/hFuqg

Answer (score 0):

Problem ended up being 'Custom Permalinks' plugin. Doesn't play nice with WPML.